# What is the best practice to query exact match of a field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

What is the best way to query exact value of a field in elasticsearch? Say for example I have:

```
profile: {
     email: "test@email.com"
}
```

How do I check if there's exactly the same `test@email.com` email in a profile?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you require exact search you can define data type of that field as [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword). If you require both partial search (analyzed) and exact search on the same field you can define a sub field for the same and refer to that subfield when exact search is required.

So the field definition looks as below:

```
"email": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to perform exact search.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "email.keyword": "test@email.com"
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Defining the type as `keyword` results in case-sensitive exact search.